# Не удается получить данные поля массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив, который вывожу `var_dump`.

```
array(1) { [7788]=> object(WC_Coupon)#7148 (20) { ["code"]=> string(4) "7788" ["id"]=> int(18852) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["discount_type"]=> string(10) "fixed_cart" ["coupon_amount"]=> string(4) "2000" ["individual_use"]=> string(2) "no" ["product_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["exclude_product_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["usage_limit"]=> string(0) "" ["usage_limit_per_user"]=> string(0) "" ["limit_usage_to_x_items"]=> string(0) "" ["usage_count"]=> string(0) "" ["expiry_date"]=> int(1461974400) ["free_shipping"]=> string(2) "no" ["product_categories"]=> array(0) { } ["exclude_product_categories"]=> array(0) { } ["exclude_sale_items"]=> string(2) "no" ["minimum_amount"]=> string(0) "" ["maximum_amount"]=> string(0) "" ["customer_email"]=> array(0) { } } }
```

Толи я туплю, но никак не могу получить значение поля `coupon_amount`. Пробую и так

```
$coupon_amount = $cart->coupon_amount; var_dump($coupon_amount);
```

и так и ничего не выводится..

```
$coupon_amount = $cart["coupon_amount"]; var_dump($coupon_amount);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле переменная `$cart` содержит массив в котором на индексе `7788` находится объект типа `WC_Coupon` который в свою очередь поле `coupon_amount`.

`$cart[7788]->coupon_amount` - должен вывести нужное значение.